# Why does the viewpoint change when switching between Eevee and Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, error

I was doing the Donut tutorial and when switching between Eevee and Cycles, the viewpoint completely changes (see below) -- the only change I have made between the two images attached is the selection of the rendering engine. Does anyone know what this is about? I have not been able to find an answer online -- but I might be asking the question wrong...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your [camera type](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/render/cameras.html?utm_source=blender-3.6.0#lens) set to "Panoramic"? It only works in Cycles and could explain why it looks different in the two rendering engines.

Comment: Yes -- thank you! (No idea how it got set to panoramic, but that was the reason...)